# Change type in a Field of a Generic List<>

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-entities

I have a List of a class that calls ***Indicator***, It needs convert the Value of an attribute **IndicatorValue** to Double.

This is the example of the class

```
    public class Indicator
{
    public int ObjID { get; set; }

    public string IndicatorValue { get; set; }
}
```

this is Dummy data of that class filled in a list.

```
            IList<Indicator> IndicatorList = new List<Indicator>() {
            new Indicator(){ ObjID=1, IndicatorValue="1.8 s"},
            new Indicator(){  ObjID=2, IndicatorValue="1.5S"},
            new Indicator(){  ObjID=3, IndicatorValue="1.7 "},
            new Indicator(){  ObjID=4, IndicatorValue="1.8 S"}
        };
```

I Replace the characters "s", S, and " " in a new list

```
            var lstResult = (from fx in IndicatorList
                         select new Indicator
                         {
                             ObjID = fx.ObjID,
                            *(Double)*IndicatorValue =  fx.IndicatorValue.Replace("S", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("s", "")

                         }
         ).ToList();
```

But I need that the Field **IndicatorValue** be converted in Double in the new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a property type at runtime.

Why not add a new property to the `Indicator` class that encapsulates the conversion:

```
public class Indicator
{
    public int ObjID { get; set; }

    public string IndicatorValue { get; set; }

    public double IndicatorValueAsDouble => double.Parse(IndicatorValue.Replace("S", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("s", ""));
}
```

Or project to a DTO:

```
public class IndicatorDTO
{
     public int ObjID { get; set; }

     public double IndicatorValue { get; set; }
}

select new IndicatorDTO
{
    ObjID = fx.ObjID,
    IndicatorValue = double.Parse(fx.IndicatorValue.Replace("S", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("s", ""));
}
```